# Por qué obtengo el error: Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Pantalla" React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Estoy trabajando una app con React Native y expo. Cuando quiero hacer la conexión de el emulador con el backend (utilizo La direccion 10.0.2.2 por defecto);

```
const fetchExercises = async () =>{
    const res = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/break')
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
}

useEffect(() =>{
    fetchExercises();
    console.log('succes')
```

me arroja un console warning:

`[Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Pantalla"]`

y también `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:2):`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya busqué en foros e intente agregar la dirección ipv4 de mi pc. Con la cual obtengo el mismo error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetchExercises es async, entonces debe de ser

```
useEffect(() =>{
   fetchExercises().then(() => console.log('succes'));
```

una solucion rapida para tu problema con el localhost, es

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

y luego usar localtunnel asi:

```
lt --port 8000
```

eso te dara una url, y esa url no te dara los errores.